# Connecting phone contacts with facebook contacts, sync.me can't find right one

Tags: contacts, sync, facebook

I've got a phone contact named Dave T. On Facebook his name is David Tiger. Sync.me can't find him for some reason, though it normally does work. I think it has to do with `Dave` vs `David` how can I fix this? What I really want is the picture beside the contact.

I've got Xperia Z2 running Lollipop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I've read, this is because of new FB restrictions (which are changed quite frequently), which don't allow SyncMe (or any other app) to use the FB friends list.

What you can do is to try to perform more operations on FB with this contact, so that other ways that the apps (like SyncMe) use to get the friends list will succeed. Maybe tagging in photos is enough.